# Envio de datos a un Web Api

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Estoy haciendo un sistema con Entity Framework y Web Api. Me ha pasado que solo puedo pasarle un objeto a la Api, no puedo mandarle un string, ¿ésto por qué es? ¿Dónde se configura que solo reciba un objeto? y no solo eso, que el objeto tiene que ser de una clase definida, no sé si se entiende, así me funciona.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Get")]
public L_Persona Get(L_Persona in_obj)
{
    L_CabeceraUbicacion a = L_Persona.get(in_obj);
    return a;
}
```

Pero así no me funciona:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Get")]
public L_Persona Get(int id)
{
    L_Persona a = L_Persona.get(id);
    return a;
}
```

Si tengo que pasar un `id`, para que funcione tengo que pasar un objeto persona con el `id` y los demas campos vacios, cuando podria pasar directamente el `id`.
También me sucede que quiero enviar una imagen y me da error también, algo del estilo

> 415 unsupported media type

¿Cómo configuro entonces que la Web Api reciba lo que yo quiera pasarle y no siempre un objeto?

Comment: ¿De qué forma estás enviando los datos de la clase? ¿Qué tipo de contenido deseas enviar y recibir?

Comment: Será entonces que los metodos que hacen la petición, yo lo hago mediante el serviocio http de angular, esta configurado para mandar JSON, entonces si pongo public L_Persona Get(int id) da error, quizá tenga que ver como hacer la peticion de otra manera para poder solo pasar el ID...GRacias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complementando la excelente respuesta del colega **Flxtr**, sólo deberías especificar en *Route* que va a recibir un id:

```
[Route("Get/{id}")]
public L_Persona Get(int id)
{
     //Código
}
```

Saludos!

Comment: De hecho, el `[Route("Get/{id}")]` sería opcional ya que lo estás definiendo en `WebApiConfig.cs`, aunque nunca está de más ponerlo :D

Answer (score 1):

El tipo de contenido que desees enviar debe estar especificado en la petición, los más frecuentes son JSON y XML:

- Para JSON es `Content-Type: application/json`
- Para XML es `Content-Type: text/xml`, o en su caso `Content-Type: application/xml`

---

Para configurar los parámetros a recibir en el Api debe ser en `App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs` donde por defecto se asigna:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Al consumir la ruta, deberá seguir la estructura:

```
https://{url base}/api/{controller}/{id}
```

De igual forma, en ese archivo, puedes definir rutas personalizadas.

Comment: yo llamo a el metodo del web api asi:
/api/Persona/insert',
method: "POST",
data: datos,(aqui un json)

pero aqui se pide que pases un id
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
o es un identificador del metodo y no un id de persona
no se si estoy haciendo bien la llamada...
gracias

Answer (score 1):

para pasarle un string desde el cliente puedes usar un query string en la URL, claro que la url depende de la configuracion de tu enrutamiento, pero el query string al final no cambia:

http://localhost/api/Controlador/Accion/?parametro1=valorParametro1&parametro2=valorParametro2

un ejemplo real:

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("get_modulos_by_rfc/")]
    public IHttpActionResult get_modulos_by_rfc(string rfc, string softwareCode)
    {}
```

en el cliente

```
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/api/empresa/get_modulos_by_rfc/?rfc=" + rfc + "&softwareCode=" + softwareCode);
```